# Preciso somar valores de uma tabela

Tags: mysql, sql

Possuo um `SELECT` e nele eu exibo a soma dos valores de venda de cada produto, teria como eu fazer um somatório total da tabela que efetuei a soma ?

```
SELECT 
     cadpro.descricao, 
     sum(itensped.total_venda) AS total_venda
FROM itensped
INNER JOIN pedido ON 
    itensped.id = pedido.id
NNER JOIN cadpro ON 
    itensped.id_cadpro = cadpro.id
INNER JOIN cadgrp ON 
    cadpro.id_grupo = cadgrp.id
       WHERE pedido.empresa = 1 
             AND pedido.filial = 1 
             AND pedido.data_venda BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31' 
             AND total_venda > 0
GROUP BY cadgrp.nome_grupo
ORDER BY  total_venda DESC LIMIT 10
```

**Resultado do Select** queria fazer um somatório total de *`total_venda`*

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Uma vez que quer o somatório total dos 10 produtos com maior valor de venda, sugeria uma sub-query. Exemplo:

```
SELECT COALESCE(descricao, 'Somatório total de vendas'),
       SUM(total_venda) Total_Venda
  FROM 
(    
    SELECT 
         cadpro.descricao,
         sum(itensped.total_venda) AS total_venda
    FROM itensped
    INNER JOIN pedido ON 
        itensped.id = pedido.id
    INNER JOIN cadpro ON 
        itensped.id_cadpro = cadpro.id
    INNER JOIN cadgrp ON 
        cadpro.id_grupo = cadgrp.id
           WHERE pedido.empresa = 1 
                 AND pedido.filial = 1 
                 AND pedido.data_venda BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31' 
                 AND total_venda > 0
    GROUP BY cadpro.descricao
    ORDER BY  total_venda DESC LIMIT 10
) Res
GROUP BY descricao WITH ROLLUP
```

Isto irá resultar num conjunto de resultados com 11 registos. Os 10 produtos com maior valor de venda e um registo com o somatório total para esses 10 produtos.

Se o objectivo é apenas devolver um único registo com o somatório total de total_venda pode fazer:

```
SELECT 'Somatório total de vendas',
       SUM(total_venda) Total_Venda
  FROM 
(    
    SELECT 
         cadpro.descricao,
         sum(itensped.total_venda) AS total_venda
    FROM itensped
    INNER JOIN pedido ON 
        itensped.id = pedido.id
    INNER JOIN cadpro ON 
        itensped.id_cadpro = cadpro.id
    INNER JOIN cadgrp ON 
        cadpro.id_grupo = cadgrp.id
           WHERE pedido.empresa = 1 
                 AND pedido.filial = 1 
                 AND pedido.data_venda BETWEEN '2017-05-01' AND '2017-05-31' 
                 AND total_venda > 0
    GROUP BY cadpro.descricao
    ORDER BY  total_venda DESC LIMIT 10
) Res
```

Comment: me ajudou do jeito que queria, muito obrigado cara. Somente na primeira solução que encontrei erro de Incorrect parameter count in the call the native function "ISNULL" mas, a segunda funcionou

Comment: @VictorT., substitui ISNULL por COALESCE. O erro deve agora ter sido corrigido.

Comment: foi sim, muito obrigado cara